# How to export native WordPress events in a form useful to Events Calendar

Tags: export, events, the-events-calendar

I have over 100 events in plain, vanilla, native WordPress events; they came from a Drupal conversion using FG Drupal to WordPress plugin. I’m not talking about Events Calendar events, Events Manager events, or anything else. Just plain WordPress default events – they appear when I click on the Events menu item in WP Admin with the thumb tack next to it.

How do I export those events so I can import them into a different event system – in my case, we will be using Events Calendar as our event manager, so that’s where my 100+ events have to end up.

What have I tried? I've tried UpDraftPlus and All-in-One WP Migration backups but they don't have the granularity I need (ie, whole database vs events for import into Events Calendar). I've searched Google and the WordPress forum.

What’s the expeditious way to do it without buying more software? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have found is to export a blank set of data for the new plugin, in this case Events Manager, and use the file generated to make a spreadsheet and paste in the rows of data that you need or add the column headings to your file and export it as CSV and import in your WordPress.

It's easier than trying to find a direct import/export. Gets very tricky when you start using custom post types that the import/exporter may not be prepared to handle. Datafeedr might be able to handle the import export if you don't want to edit the file.